# Can I have more than one VPN server on my home network?

Tags: vpn, raspberry-pi

I have a VPN server currently set up on my DD-WRT router, but I want to try to create a second one with a raspberry pi.  Do these conflict?  Does it make sense to have more than one VPN server on a network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple VPN servers however they will have to operate on different ports. It's very common practice to have several VPN servers for redundancy.